# How to delete a photo from Appearance Preferences's list?

Tags: 11.04, desktop-background

I had some time ago a photo of a person as my desktop background image. Now this photo remains in the list of photos in *Appearance Preferences ➜ Background*. Is there a way to remove it, or reset those photos to show only the Ubuntu original ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Gnome Desktop User Guide](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.32/prefs-appearance.html.en#goscustdesk-TBL-14):

> **Remove**
>
> Choose the image that you want to remove, then click **Remove**. This
> removes the image from the list of available wallpapers; however, it does not delete the image from your computer.